# How to select top items ordered by SUM for each month in the time range?

Tags: sql, soql

At the moment, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    Yr, Mnth, Product, SUM(Price * Amount)
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Random_product_name AS Product, Random_price AS Price, 
         Random_quantity AS Amount,
         Random_order_dt AS Order_date, 
         YEAR(Random_order_dt) AS Yr, MONTH(Random_order_dt) AS Mnth
     FROM 
         Random_table_1 a
     JOIN 
         Random_table_2 b ON a.Random_ID = b.Random_ID
     WHERE 
         a.Random_product_name LIKE 'XX_%' 
         AND a.Random_country = 'XX'
         AND a.Random_price != 0 
         AND b.Random_order_dt BETWEEN 'Jan 01 2019 12:00AM' AND 'Jul 01 2021 12:00AM') x
GROUP BY 
    Yr, Mnth, Product
ORDER BY 
    Yr, CONVERT(INT, Mnth), CONVERT(INT, SUM(Price*Amount)) DESC
```

Don't pay attention to the detail, the real query looks a bit different, of course. But result of it might look like this:

| Yr | Mnth | Product | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | A | 100 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | B | 90 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | C | 80 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | D | 70 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | E | 60 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | F | 50 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | G | 40 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | B | 120 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | A | 110 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | D | 90 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | C | 80 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | E | 60 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | G | 30 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | F | 20 000 |

And so on up until July 2021. Sum of products changes every month and
what I would like to achieve is to display only top 3 of them for each month, but in one table, like this:

| Yr | Mnth | Product | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | A | 100 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | B | 90 000 |
| 2019 | 1 | C | 80 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | B | 120 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | A | 110 000 |
| 2019 | 2 | D | 90 000 |

And so on. Again, up until July 2021.

The query is simplified. In reality it looks a bit more complicated, but I hope it is understandable enough what I want to accomplish. I don't know how to proceed, so I would appreciate any help you can provide! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) might help you

I couldn't test and i know it's not a pretty solution it but i think this is the general idea:

```
    SELECT * FROM  
        (SELECT 
            Yr, Mnth, Product, sold
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY Yr, Mnth, Product 
                    ORDER BY sold DESC
            ) item_rank
        FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP 1000 
                Yr, Mnth, Product, SUM(Price * Amount) as sold
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                    Random_product_name AS Product, Random_price AS Price, 
                    Random_quantity AS Amount,
                    Random_order_dt AS Order_date, 
                    YEAR(Random_order_dt) AS Yr, MONTH(Random_order_dt) AS Mnth
                FROM 
                    Random_table_1 a
                JOIN 
                    Random_table_2 b ON a.Random_ID = b.Random_ID
                WHERE 
                    a.Random_product_name LIKE 'XX_%' 
                    AND a.Random_country = 'XX'
                    AND a.Random_price != 0 
                    AND b.Random_order_dt BETWEEN 'Jan 01 2019 12:00AM' AND 'Jul 01 2021 12:00AM') x
            GROUP BY 
                Yr, Mnth, Product
            ORDER BY 
                Yr, CONVERT(INT, Mnth), CONVERT(INT, SUM(Price*Amount)) DESC
        )
    )
    WHERE item_rank <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row_number with a partition_by clause with your select statement and then use the result in your where clause.

To add to the top-select :

```
 row_number() over(partition by Yr, Mnth order by SUM(Price * Amount) desc) as rownum
```

Then add a select on top of with the following where clause:

```
WHERE rownum <= 3
```